# Azure AD B2C Github identity provider does not provide any claims

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to use the AAD B2C Github identity provider to authorize users in my app. To create a user I need at least get an email from it - but I get nothing. I did set up everything according to docs and I can see in the AAD B2C Users list that `Name` is set up correctly for a new user, but `User Principal Name` where email should be is null

Here is JWT answer

```
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "X5eXk4xyojNFum1kl2Ytv8dlNP4-c57dO6QGTVBwaNk"
}.{
  "exp": 1611879546,
  "nbf": 1611875946,
  "ver": "1.0",
  "iss": "https://apichat.b2clogin.com/4d39cd56-4c18-4bc7-aaa8-36bf91191c8c/v2.0/",
  "sub": "dfe38752-113e-4431-b1bd-23dd53119369",
  "aud": "341eea81-859c-485c-baea-2cc9f75f6512",
  "nonce": "defaultNonce",
  "iat": 1611875946,
  "auth_time": 1611875946,
  "idp_access_token": "c5c79a8f49c44575cf127fc3c64aaa5710a0a465",
  "idp": "github.com",
  "tfp": "B2C_1_susi_debug"
}.[Signature]
```

What do I missing?

**Added**

After some studying, I have a suspicion that the Github provider here either does not have the required scopes or mappings. I don't see any ways to add it so far. Potentially that might be solved by a generic OpenID Connect provider but Github does not support `well-known/openid-connect-discovery` and I have no option to manually set endpoints in AAD B2C.

So far I don't see any way to connect GitHub to my AAD B2C and get that darn email - why the biggest cloud platform does not fully support the biggest dev repository when they have the same owner is beyond my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution I found looks like that

1. Set `Display Name` and `Identity Provider Access Token` in Application Claims of your User Flow
2. On GitHub auth you will get `name` aka `username` and `idp_access_token` aka `token`
3. That's allow us to call github user api `curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user`
4. By default user api returns public user profile, which might not have a set email
5. `curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user/emails` will return all user associated emails
6. We need the primary one

```
{
    "email": "***@gmail.com",
    "primary": true,
    "verified": true,
    "visibility": "public"
}
```